# Need to monitor the time interval of 0 and 1

Tags: python, datetime, time, toggle, real-time

I am reading a signal that is toggling between 0 and 1 continuously. I need monitor the time interval for which it is 0 and the time interval for which it is 1 and then print it.

How do I do that using python? I need real time calculations. The interval is between 60ms to 100ms.

Comment: how do you sample the signal and what precision are you looking for?

Comment: btw you need to be aware of the [Nyquist rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate)

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Can't you use `time.time` to get time when you get new signal and substract from previous time?